# Django App with data from Postgres and dataviz in d3.js

Tags: python, django, postgresql, d3.js

This is my first brush with Django. I'm trying to create an app which has a textinput whose value needs to be queried in the Postgres database. The results will be read into a Pandas dataframe and some aggregations are done, and then the result set would be converted into json that feeds a d3 force directed graph.

I Created a model that has the source, target and weight

```
class Graph(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    target = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    weight = models.IntegerField()
```

I viewed many tutorials online but couldn't get a sense of where to write the code to make the psycopg2 calls to fetch results (is it views.py?) and then how to map the aggregated values to the objects in the model above. Or does the ORM take care of mapping? Please assist with the workflow. Thanks.